# How to create a new entry using automation in a SharePoint list when another SharePoint list column is modified?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate

I have two sharepoint lists that contain the same data and columns. One list contains all the active projects info and the second  list will contain the projects info once the project is completed.

I want to know how to automate a process that will move an entries data from the active projects list to the completed projects list once the column "completed date" is filled in on the active projects list.

Answer (score 0):

We can create an Event Receiver to monitor sharepoint list item created,added and deleted by following link:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/